# C++11 recursive atomic spinlock

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

Could you please review my spinlock implementation?

```
class spinlock {
private:
    static const std::thread::id lock_is_free;
    std::atomic<std::thread::id> lock_owner;
    int lock_count;

public:
    spinlock() : lock_owner(lock_is_free), lock_count(0) {
    }

    void lock() {
        static thread_local std::thread::id this_thread_local = std::this_thread::get_id();
        auto this_thread = this_thread_local;

        for (auto id = lock_is_free; ; id = lock_is_free) {
            if (lock_owner.compare_exchange_strong(id, this_thread, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { ++lock_count; break; }
            id = this_thread;
            if (lock_owner.compare_exchange_strong(id, this_thread, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { ++lock_count; break; }
        }
    }

    void unlock() {
        assert(lock_owner.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == std::this_thread::get_id());
        if (lock_count > 0 && --lock_count == 0) {
            lock_owner.store(lock_is_free, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }
};

const std::thread::id spinlock::lock_is_free;
```

Comment: It's not reentrant (under which I understand that `spLock.lock();spLock.lock(); spLock.unlock();spLock.unlock();` works as expected)

Comment: That is not the definition of reentrant. Locks that behave like in your description are usually called "recursive" locks.

Comment: @FelixBytow the other reentrant definition would be not changing globals to allow it to be called thread-safely and recursively but that is redundant when talking about thread safety and this function is not recursive.

Comment: yes you're right @ratchetfreak, @felix-bytow it's not a re-entrant but rather recursive indeed. `lck.lock(); lck.lock();` works. i think the only problem in my code is - you can unlock a lock held by other thread but i typically use `std::lock_guard` with it so unless i got the lock i would not call `unlock()`

Comment: @dundeclared but then the lock should only unlock after the *second* `unlock()` in your code it will unlock at the first

Comment: thanks @ratchetfreak added a lock counter which is indeed much needed

Comment: Please see: [What can I do after I have received an answer?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: Also on GCC (Linux) `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` is lock-free http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c74ad5a84ad90333  but on MSVS2013(Windows) it is **not lock-free**. In the file xthrcommon.h type `std::thread::id` contains this:`typedef struct { void *_Hnd; unsigned int _Id; } _Thrd_imp_t;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use of TLS

I'm not completely sold on your use of TLS. This looks like a premature optimization to me, that said if you have measured and it improves your performance then keep it.

## Static member

I think it would be better style to not have this static member but this is highly subjective.

## Readability

Your code here:

```
    for (auto id = lock_is_free; ; id = lock_is_free) {
        if (lock_owner.compare_exchange_strong(id, this_thread, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { ++lock_count; break; }
        id = this_thread;
        if (lock_owner.compare_exchange_strong(id, this_thread, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { ++lock_count; break; }
    }
```

is very difficult to read for me. In fact I'm struggling to understand what the intended behaviour is. To me it looks like what you really wanted was:

```
// If we're being locked recursively, this will always compare false
// (insert your desired memory_order here) because no one can fiddle
// with `lock_owner` while we have the lock. If we're not entering
// recursively then this will always compare true because the thread
// doing the checking can only be in one place at one time. 
if(lock_owner.load() != this_thread){
    // Okay so it's not a recursive call.
    do{
        auto id = lock_is_free;
    }while(!lock_owner.compare_exchange_weak(id, this_thread, 
                                             std::memory_order_acquire, 
                                             std::memory_order_relaxed));
}
// Okay in any event, recursive or not we have the lock now.
lock_count++;
return;
```

**Note:** I change `compare_exchange_strong` to `compare_exchange_weak` this is recommended when you call `compare_exchange` in a loop as per [std::atomic::compare_exchange (cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange).

I would much prefer this implementation of `unlock()`

```
void unlock(){
    assert(lock_owner.load() == std::this_thread::get_id());
    assert(lock_count != 0);

    --lock_count;
    if(lock_count == 0){
        lock_owner.store(lock_is_free, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}
```

Following the style of [std::mutex::unlock()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) stating that calling `unlock` when the calling thread doesn't own the lock is undefined behaviour we can simply satisfy ourselves with the two asserts to aid during debug-time.

Comment: thanks Emily. do you think `compare_exchange_weak` is sufficient, strong is not needed?

Comment: I think you mean `assert(lock_count != 0);` in your 2nd unlock assert. Other than that, nice code review!

Comment: @dundeclared If you look at the documentation provided by Emily L., you can read "The weak forms of the functions are allowed to fail spuriously. [...] in a loop, the weak version will yield better performance on some platforms." Since we are in a spinloop, you can use the weak version.

Comment: @miklas nice catch! Fixed it.

Comment: i believe every `==` or `!=` of `atomic` does `load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)` under the hood i.e. most expensive memory barrier, isn't it? please also have a look at UPD2. i really need to squeeze every nanosecond here so trying to even minimize branching

Comment: @dundeclared Depending on your architecture, the memory orderings may all just be the same. Read the documentation for your platform. If you need to squeeze every last ounce out, you need to start profiling and measuring otherwise you could just as well be making it slower. Measure! Measure! Measure! Did I say measure?

Comment: `lock_owner != this_thread` and `lock_owner == std::this_thread::get_id()` should read as `lock_owner.load() != this_thread` and `lock_owner.load() == std::this_thread::get_id()`, as std::atomic() does not overload operator==() or operator!=().

Comment: @Kaiserludi you're welcome to edit.

Comment: I have just tried that after your invitation to do so, but my edit got rejected with the statement "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

Comment: @Kaiserludi I overrode them.